# AdWord Script Export to BigQuery "Empty Response"

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Utilizing the following AdWords Script to export to BigQuery, the BigQuery.Jobs.insert is causing the script to terminate due to "Empty response". Any reason the call is not getting a response?

```
    var ACCOUNTS = ['xxx','xxx']; 

    var CONFIG = {
      BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID: 'xxx',
      BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID: 'xxx',

      // Truncate existing data, otherwise will append.
      TRUNCATE_EXISTING_DATASET: true,
      TRUNCATE_EXISTING_TABLES: true,

      // Back up reports to Google Drive.
      WRITE_DATA_TO_DRIVE: false,
      // Folder to put all the intermediate files.
      DRIVE_FOLDER: 'Adwords Big Query Test',

      // Default date range over which statistics fields are retrieved.
      DEFAULT_DATE_RANGE: '20140101,20140105',

      // Lists of reports and fields to retrieve from AdWords.
      REPORTS: [{NAME: 'KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT',
         CONDITIONS: 'WHERE Impressions>0',
         FIELDS: {'AccountDescriptiveName' : 'STRING',
                  'Date' : 'STRING',
                  'CampaignId' : 'STRING',
                  'CampaignName' : 'STRING',
                  'AdGroupId' : 'STRING',
                  'AdGroupName' : 'STRING',
                  'Id' : 'STRING',
                  'Criteria' : 'STRING',
                  'KeywordMatchType' : 'STRING',
                  'AdNetworkType1' : 'STRING',
                  'AdNetworkType2' : 'STRING',
                  'Device' : 'STRING',
                  'AveragePosition' : 'STRING',
                  'QualityScore' : 'STRING',
                  'CpcBid' : 'STRING',
                  'TopOfPageCpc' : 'STRING',
                  'Impressions' : 'STRING',
                  'Clicks' : 'STRING',
                  'ConvertedClicks' : 'STRING',
                  'Cost' : 'STRING',
                  'Conversions' : 'STRING'
                 }
        }],

      RECIPIENT_EMAILS: [
        'xxx',
      ]
    };

    function main() {
      createDataset();
      for (var i = 0; i < CONFIG.REPORTS.length; i++) {
        var reportConfig = CONFIG.REPORTS[i];
        createTable(reportConfig);
      }

      folder = getDriveFolder();

      // Get an account iterator.
      var accountIterator = MccApp.accounts().withIds(ACCOUNTS).withLimit(10).get();
      var jobIdMap = {};
      while (accountIterator.hasNext()) {
         // Get the current account.
         var account = accountIterator.next();

         // Select the child account.
         MccApp.select(account);

         // Run reports against child account.
         var accountJobIds = processReports(folder, account.getCustomerId());
         jobIdMap[account.getCustomerId()] = accountJobIds;
      }

      waitTillJobsComplete(jobIdMap);
      sendEmail(jobIdMap);
    }


    function createDataset() {
       if (datasetExists()) {
        if (CONFIG.TRUNCATE_EXISTING_DATASET) {
          BigQuery.Datasets.remove(CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID,
            CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID, {'deleteContents' : true});
          Logger.log('Truncated dataset.');
        } else {
          Logger.log('Dataset %s already exists.  Will not recreate.',
           CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID);
          return;
        }
      }

      // Create new dataset.
      var dataSet = BigQuery.newDataset();
      dataSet.friendlyName = CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID;
      dataSet.datasetReference = BigQuery.newDatasetReference();
      dataSet.datasetReference.projectId = CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID;
      dataSet.datasetReference.datasetId = CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID;

      dataSet = BigQuery.Datasets.insert(dataSet, CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID);
      Logger.log('Created dataset with id %s.', dataSet.id);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if dataset already exists in project.
     *
     * @return {boolean} Returns true if dataset already exists.
     */
    function datasetExists() {
      // Get a list of all datasets in project.
      var datasets = BigQuery.Datasets.list(CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID);
      var datasetExists = false;
      // Iterate through each dataset and check for an id match.
      if (datasets.datasets != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < datasets.datasets.length; i++) {
          var dataset = datasets.datasets[i];
          if (dataset.datasetReference.datasetId == CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID) {
            datasetExists = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return datasetExists;
    }

    function createTable(reportConfig) {
      if (tableExists(reportConfig.NAME)) {
        if (CONFIG.TRUNCATE_EXISTING_TABLES) {
          BigQuery.Tables.remove(CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID,
              CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID, reportConfig.NAME);
          Logger.log('Truncated dataset %s.', reportConfig.NAME);
        } else {
          Logger.log('Table %s already exists.  Will not recreate.',
              reportConfig.NAME);
          return;
        }
      }

      // Create new table.
      var table = BigQuery.newTable();
      var schema = BigQuery.newTableSchema();
      var bigQueryFields = [];

      // Add account column to table.
      var accountFieldSchema = BigQuery.newTableFieldSchema();
      accountFieldSchema.description = 'AccountId';
      accountFieldSchema.name = 'AccountId';
      accountFieldSchema.type = 'STRING';
      bigQueryFields.push(accountFieldSchema);

      // Add each field to table schema.
      var fieldNames = Object.keys(reportConfig.FIELDS);
      for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        var fieldName = fieldNames[i];
        var bigQueryFieldSchema = BigQuery.newTableFieldSchema();
        bigQueryFieldSchema.description = fieldName;
        bigQueryFieldSchema.name = fieldName;
        bigQueryFieldSchema.type = reportConfig.FIELDS[fieldName];

        bigQueryFields.push(bigQueryFieldSchema);
      }

      schema.fields = bigQueryFields;
      table.schema = schema;
      table.friendlyName = reportConfig.NAME;

      table.tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
      table.tableReference.datasetId = CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID;
      table.tableReference.projectId = CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID;
      table.tableReference.tableId = reportConfig.NAME;

      table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID,
          CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID);

      Logger.log('Created table with id %s.', table.id);
    }

    function tableExists(tableId) {
      // Get a list of all tables in the dataset.
      var tables = BigQuery.Tables.list(CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID,
          CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID);
      var tableExists = false;
      // Iterate through each table and check for an id match.
      if (tables.tables != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tables.tables.length; i++) {
          var table = tables.tables[i];
          if (table.tableReference.tableId == tableId) {
            tableExists = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return tableExists;
    }

    function processReports(folder, accountId) {
      var jobIds = [];

      // Iterate over each report type.
      for (var i = 0; i < CONFIG.REPORTS.length; i++) {
        var reportConfig = CONFIG.REPORTS[i];
        Logger.log('Running report %s for account %s', reportConfig.NAME,
            accountId);
        // Get data as csv
        var csvData = retrieveAdwordsReport(reportConfig, accountId);

        // If configured, back up data.
        if (CONFIG.WRITE_DATA_TO_DRIVE) {
          var fileName = reportConfig.NAME + '_' + accountId;
          folder.createFile(fileName, csvData, MimeType.CSV);
          Logger.log('Exported data to Drive folder ' +
                 CONFIG.DRIVE_FOLDER + ' for report ' + fileName);
        }

        // Convert to Blob format.
        var blobData = Utilities.newBlob(csvData, 'application/octet-stream');
        // Load data
        var jobId = loadDataToBigquery(reportConfig, blobData);
        jobIds.push(jobId);
      }
      return jobIds;
    }

    function retrieveAdwordsReport(reportConfig, accountId) {
      var fieldNames = Object.keys(reportConfig.FIELDS);
      var report = AdWordsApp.report(
        'SELECT ' + fieldNames.join(',') +
        ' FROM ' + reportConfig.NAME + ' ' + reportConfig.CONDITIONS +
        ' DURING ' + CONFIG.DEFAULT_DATE_RANGE);
      var rows = report.rows();
      var csvRows = [];
      // Header row
      csvRows.push('AccountId,'+fieldNames.join(','));

      // Iterate over each row.
      while (rows.hasNext()) {
        var row = rows.next();
        var csvRow = [];
        csvRow.push(accountId);

        for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
          var fieldName = fieldNames[i];
          var fieldValue = row[fieldName].toString();
          var fieldType = reportConfig.FIELDS[fieldName];
          /* Strip off % and perform any other formatting here.
          if ((fieldType == 'FLOAT' || fieldType == 'INTEGER') &&
              fieldValue.charAt(fieldValue.length - 1) == '%') {
            fieldValue = fieldValue.substring(0, fieldValue.length - 1);
          }*/
          // Add double quotes to any string values.
          if (fieldType == 'STRING') {
            fieldValue = fieldValue.replace(',', ''); //Handle fields with comma in value returned
            fieldValue = fieldValue.replace('"', ''); //Handle fields with double quotes in value returned
            fieldValue = fieldValue.replace('+', ''); //Handle fields with "+" in value returned
            fieldValue = '"' + fieldValue + '"';
          }
          csvRow.push(fieldValue);
        }
        csvRows.push(csvRow.join(','));
      }
      Logger.log('Downloaded ' + reportConfig.NAME + ' for account ' + accountId +
          ' with ' + csvRows.length + ' rows.');
      return csvRows.join('\n');
    }

    function getDriveFolder() {
      var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(CONFIG.DRIVE_FOLDER);
      // Assume first folder is the correct one.
      if (folders.hasNext()) {
       Logger.log('Folder name found.  Using existing folder.');
       return folders.next();
      }
      return DriveApp.createFolder(CONFIG.DRIVE_FOLDER);
    }

    function loadDataToBigquery(reportConfig, data) {
  function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() + s4();
  }

  var makeId = guid();
  var job = {
        jobReference: {
          jobId: makeId
        },
        configuration: {
          load: {
            destinationTable: {
              projectId: CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID,
              datasetId: CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID,
              tableId: reportConfig.NAME
            },
            skipLeadingRows: 1,
            ignoreUnknownValues: true,
            allowJaggedRows: true,
            allowLargeResults: true
          }
        }
      };

        var insertJob = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID, data);
        Logger.log('Load job started for %s. Check on the status of it here: ' +
                   'https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/%s', reportConfig.NAME,
                   CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID);
        return job.jobReference.jobId;

    }

    function waitTillJobsComplete(jobIdMap) {
      var complete = false;
      var remainingJobs = [];
      var accountIds = Object.keys(jobIdMap);
      for (var i = 0; i < accountIds.length; i++){
        var accountJobIds = jobIdMap[accountIds[i]];
        remainingJobs.push.apply(remainingJobs, accountJobIds);
      }
      while (!complete) {
        if (AdWordsApp.getExecutionInfo().getRemainingTime() < 5){
          Logger.log('Script is about to timeout, jobs ' + remainingJobs.join(',') +
            ' are still incomplete.');
        }
        remainingJobs = getIncompleteJobs(remainingJobs);
        if (remainingJobs.length == 0) {
          complete = true;
        }
        if (!complete) {
          Logger.log(remainingJobs.length + ' jobs still being processed.');
          // Wait 5 seconds before checking status again.
          Utilities.sleep(5000);
        }
      }
      Logger.log('All jobs processed.');
    }

    function getIncompleteJobs(jobIds) {
      var remainingJobIds = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < jobIds.length; i++) {
        var jobId = jobIds[i];
        var getJob = BigQuery.Jobs.get(CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID, jobId);
        if (getJob.status.state != 'DONE') {
          remainingJobIds.push(jobId);
        }
      }
      return remainingJobIds;
    }
```

It appears the "Empty Response" error is being thrown on:

```
var insertJob = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID, data);
```

Have tried quite a few tweaks, but the answer doesn't appear to obvious to me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: it doesn't look to me that error is at BigQuery.Jobs.insert! Why you think so? What exactly error you are getting?

Comment: There are two reasons: 
-if you follow the log, it would be the next function after the last successful log entry
-it calls out that line specifically:

Created dataset with id xxx.
Created table with id xxx.
Folder name found.  Using existing folder.
Running report KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT for account xxx
Downloaded KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT for account xxx with 52284 rows.
Exported data to Drive folder Adwords Big Query Test for report KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT_xxx
Empty response (line 396)

Line 396 is:

var insertJob = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID, data);

Comment: to be on safe side - can you try to add projectId to jobReference of job - jobReference: {projectId: CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID, jobId: makeId},

Comment: Just gave this a shot, got the same error message.

Comment: have another suggestion but it is too big for comment so I put it as answer - even though shooting in the air :o(

Comment: The three argument jobs.insert means to perform a media upload. I'm not sure what the actual problem is, but my guess is that something is wrong with the 'data' field.

Comment: I noticed that you're writing it to google drive; bigquery support for federated query over google drive (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources) is in alpha.  You just need to use the URI of the csv file (assuming it is a csv file) in gdrive.

Comment: The script shown is essentially the script published by Google to export AdWords reports to BigQuery, with a few minor tweaks, so any logic to build the 'data' blob were created by the Google team that wrote this code. Any ideas what could be causing it? I reviewed the CSV it writes to Drive, and I can see no obvious errors in the format.

Comment: The "empty response" error means that it isn't BigQuery returning an error; it is likely the media upload component (invoked before the request gets to the BigQuery servers). Not that it matters to you if your code isn't working. But that is why I'm suggesting a non-media upload version. (also, does it work if you don't specify a job reference?)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I noticed that your datasetExists() function uses the list operation to find the dataset. You should use dataset.get() to check for existence of a dataset: list is eventually consistent, so you may miss a just-created dataset, and the list implementation doesn't deal with pagination so if you get too many datasets you may not see yours in the first page of results.

Comment: Similar issue with checking for table existence, although in that case you could just use WRITE_TRUNCATE on the load job rather than an explicit delete/recreate of the destination table.

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong but - I think that problem was with jobId because of issue with guid() function  - missing "+" sign.

```
  function guid() {
    function s4() {
      return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() s4() + s4() + s4();
  }
```

Why not to use jobId from Response like below?

```
var job = {
  configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID,
          datasetId: CONFIG.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID,
          tableId: reportConfig.NAME
        },
        skipLeadingRows: 1,
        ignoreUnknownValues: true,
        allowJaggedRows: true,
        allowLargeResults: true
      }
  }
};

var insertJob = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID, data);
Logger.log('Load job started for %s. Check on the status of it here: ' +
    'https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/%s', reportConfig.NAME,
     CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID);
return insertJob.jobReference.jobId;
```

> Added

In this case I would suggest to log jobId (makeId = guid()) and get job status following below link https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get#try-it

Enter ProjectId and JobId and you at least will see what is going on with your job!!

Comment: I had already caught the + sign error and corrected it, but still received the error. Also, the initial method I was using was to retrieve the jobId as you have shown, but I was getting that error, so I attempted this method as a troubleshooting step, but it did not work either.

Comment: I would love to check on the job status, but it is not even hitting the BigQuery project, which is why I truly believe the error is occurring on the particular insert function. It seems to be it is getting an "Empty response" because the action is not executing, but I cannot figure out what is causing it.

Comment: understood, that is btw why I recommended to add explicitly projectId to jobReference.

Comment: as next (assuming CONFIG.BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID set correctly) - I would trace **blobData** in var jobId = loadDataToBigquery(reportConfig, blobData)

Answer (score 0):

AdWords places a "--" in for null values. If you define your report fields as anything but string (e.g., float, integer, etc.) the insert will fail because it can't convert the dash dash to a float or integer.

Try setting all of your fields to string and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the WRITE_DATA_TO_DRIVE parameter to true to confirm that the report export is successful? How large is the result? I get the same error when attempting an insert greater than 10MB (~25k rows depending on columns). If the file export to Google Drive looks good, you can add a condition to the while loop in retrieveAdwordsReport to limit the file size. There was also a post on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-scripts mentioning an issue when including AdNetworkType columns: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adwords-scripts/adnetworktype2%7Csort:relevance/adwords-scripts/yK57JHCt3Cw/Cl1SjFaQBQAJ.

Limit result size:

```
var processedRows = 0;

// Iterate over each row.
while (rows.hasNext() && ++processedRows < 5000) {
    var row = rows.next();
    var csvRow = [];
    csvRow.push(accountId);

    if (processedRows % 1000 == 0)
    {
        Logger.log('Processed %s rows.',processedRows);
    }
...
```

Comment: Congrats on your first answer! Can you add a code sample to this answer?